# Postgres: Generated column with parenthesis operation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wanna add a generated column in my PostgreSQL table. The problem is when I use operation with parenthesis, I got zero results.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
add COLUMN my_column decimal(4,3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((price-buy_price)/price) STORED;
```

All the result in my_column is 0.000. Then I try to avoid the parenthesis in my operation so my query looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
add COLUMN my_column2 decimal(4,3) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (price-buy_price/price) STORED;
```

That's work but the result is not what I want. I wonder why it fails every time I use parenthesis and it works when I do operations like (a+b) or (a+b/c) or (a*b-c/d) etc.

Is anyone has the solution? Thank you.

Comment: @DaleK Oh? Sorry I am new at DB management and don't know the difference between that. Ok, I will edit my question, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=df4a8af3cd134c0e1720e6f60af701e7

Comment: @Nick Ah, my column type of price and buy_price are an integer. I think that's why I got zero results. Let's check <https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0af0cc4f21b8e6e737321ee8ee7e7da0>

Comment: Yup, that's the problem. Changing the formula to `(1.0 * (price-buy_price)/price)` solves it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=228c783191b6e3d1c6ecd4abd52a8202

Comment: No worries - glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your columns are integer columns the division is also an integer division leaving you with no decimal digits. You need to cast at least one of the expressions in the division:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
   add my_column decimal(4,3)  
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( (price-buy_price) / price::numeric) STORED;
```

Comment: Cool, that's also work. But what the difference if multiplied by 1.0? like `(1.0 * (price-buy_price)/price)`

Comment: @HermawanWiwid: no real difference, just different coding style. The `1.0 *` also forces a non-integer expression (because `1.0` is a float constant)